# Exchange 2007: Reseeding multiple databases at the same time

Tags: exchange-2007

In my environment I have exchange 2007 sp2 with 7 DB's in a CCR configuration. After trying to switch from the primary node to the passive node for maintenance,  an error occurred. Now the primary node is active and I need to reseed several DB's to the passive node.

My question is: can I reseed multiple DB's at the same time, or should I do them one by one? Any advise? Thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 1):

So, I setup some metrics to test the effects of the environment while trying to reseed multiple DB's. The IOPS of my storage went up, so my users would notice a performance impact if this was performed during business hours.

In conclusion: yes you can reseed multiple databases, but you will take a larger performance hit due to the IOPS of your storage. If you can take the load and are not worried about affecting user experience, then performing multiple reseeds of DB's is possible.